# access firebase data id within push

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

complete noob here.

Trying to retrieve the firebase unique id from the first data push to use in the second so that I can reference the data between the two data sets. I used stackoverflow answers to retrieve the key, but my code didnt work.

(If you have a better way of referencing the two items other than utilizing firebase unique id, Im all for it!)  thanks!!

```
export const GROUP_CREATE = 'group_create';
export const groupCreate = ({ name, course, members }) => {
  const { currentUser } = firebase.auth();

  return (dispatch) => {
    var pushedRef = firebase.database().ref(`/groups`).push({ name })
    var dataId = pushedRef.key
      .then(
        firebase.database().ref('/groups')
          .push({ name, dataId, course, members }))
      .then(() => {
        dispatch({ type: GROUP_CREATE });
        Actions.groupMain({ type: 'reset' });
      });
  };
};
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out!

```
export const GROUP_CREATE = 'group_create';
export const groupCreate = ({ name, course, members }) => {
  const { currentUser } = firebase.auth();
  var myRef = firebase.database().ref('/groups').push();
  var groupId = myRef.key;

  return (dispatch) => {
    myRef.push({ name, course, members })
      .then(
        firebase.database().ref(`/users/${currentUser.uid}/groups`)
          .push({ name, groupId }))
      .then(() => {
        dispatch({ type: GROUP_CREATE });
        Actions.groupMain({ type: 'reset' });
      });
  };
};
```